# When lists are thread safe in python, is it safe to delete them?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a multi threaded application in Python 3 and have a setter and getter method of a list. The setter method appends an element to the list, while the getter method deletes all elements of the list after returning them.

The setter method looks like the following, which is in a larger async function:

```
while self.semaphor:
   print("waiting...")
   time.sleep(0.001)
self.semaphor=True
self.messages.append(msg)
print("appended data!")
```

While the getter method looks like the following:

```
while self.semaphor:
    time.sleep(0.001)
self.semaphor = True
l = self.messages
self.messages = []
self.semaphor = False
if len(l) == 0:
   return None
else:
   return l
```

However the application crashes without any error messages (probably hidden due to multithreaded output in the command line) right after the prinst statetement "append data" - So I was wondering if the code snippets are thread safe and correct?

Comment: Your `self.semaphore` flag is not thread safe, hence you can have 2 writes at the same time, also can occur a threadlock situation.

Comment: Your code is not thread-safe, there is a race-condition in setting the `semaphore` attribute. Use a real semaphore.

Comment: To conculde, appending data to lists is thread safe, but variables are not in Python?

Comment: Besides, a semaphore is the wrong object to use here, your actual usecase would require a lock instead.

Comment: @Kev1n91: Python threads are switched at the *bytecode level*; each bytecode is an instruction for the interpreter loop. List appending involves multiple bytecode, but only the final CALL bytecode does the list alteration and is thread-safe provided the list object is the standard built-in object.

Comment: @Kev1n91: Your problem, however, is that the thread can easily switch between testing if `self.semaphore` is no longer true in a `while` loop, and another thread then setting it to True again. So you exit the `while` loop with `semaphore` set *back to True by another thread*, both threads thinking they have the lock.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you very much - instead of using a lock, could I not use a binary semaphor?

Comment: @Kev1n91: sure, but that's overkill. A semaphore uses a condition and lock in the implementation. You don't *need* the extra overhead, so don't use it either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not threadsafe, because your `self.semaphore` handling is not thread-safe. Two threads can read `self.semaphore` as `False`, before either of them have set it to `True`, as thread switches can take place at any point between instructions.

What you want to use is a [proper thread lock object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) (a semaphore is the wrong primitive to use here).

When creating your instance, set a `self.messages_lock = threading.Lock()` attribute, and whenever you need to alter your `messages` list, use:

```
with self.messages_lock:
    # locked block of code, guaranteed to be thread-safe.
```

or

```
try:
    while not self.messages_lock.acquire(timeout=0.01):
        print("waiting...")
    # locked block of code, guaranteed to be thread-safe.
finally:
    self.messages_lock.release()
```

if you must have a thread that prints out that it is waiting for a lock.